# Check if send_keys is sending the key?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set-up a condition where the script checks whether a web element is present or not. If present, `actions.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)`.

```
if len(str(driver.find_element_by_class_name("blnewform_wrapper"))) >0:
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
    print("I sent escape")
else:
     print("Didn't find the form")
print(count)
```

I get an output:

> I sent escape

But the form is still in the forefront. When I click escape on the page it exits. So I am just wondering how exactly to check whether the ESCAPE key is being sent or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *have not performed the actions*, replace:

```
actions.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
```

with:

```
actions.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
```

As far as making sure it was sent - `send_keys()` would throw an error if an element you are sending keys to is not interactable (usually that means not visible or disabled). You may also recheck the visibility of the form after sending the keys.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried checking with try and got no exception, was so confused.